# What does this part mean in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

What does this part mean in Makefile?

```
    1 CC=gcc
    2 CXX=g++
    3 RM=rm
    4 PROTOC=protoc
    5 ODB=odb
```

Sorry, I'm a beginner

Comment: As a beginner, I recommend you read the manual rather than trying to learn by asking questions on SO: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're setting up substitutions so that you can later have a command like:

```
$(RM) x.o
```

and it will magically become, when executing:

```
rm x.o
```

It allows you to (for example) change it later to be `rm -rf` and you only change it in one place.

Typically you'll see things like:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o object_file.o source_file.c
```

If you compile a compile of hundred C source files, and you suddenly discover they all needed a new `-I` directive, you probably *want* that in one single place :-)

See [the "variables" section of the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html#Using-Variables) for (much) more detail, if you wish.

---

We also use it in our shop for making our builds somewhat more "readable", things like:

```
PERM_FOR_EXE=chmod 700
PERM_FOR_CFG=chmod 400
PERM_FOR_DATA=chmod 500

RM=rm
FORCE_RM=rm -f
RM_DIR_AND_BELOW=rm -rf

PROTO_FOR_PY=protoc --output=betterproto
PROTO_FOR_CPP=protoc --output=cpp
PROTO_FOR_BCPL=echo FAT CHANCE
```